# iOS - Relaunch app on orientation change?

Tags: ios

On iOS, is it possible to relaunch an app automatically when the device orientation changes? Android has this feature (just make sure  android:configChanges does not include orientation).

Comment: Why do you need to relaunch?

Comment: As for my app it is easier to start relayout from scratch rather than recompute the layout for orientation change.

Comment: As I know there is no way to relaunch it like this. But you should design the layouts for your all the scenarios when you start writing

Comment: by "Relunch" do you mean that you want all variables that are saved in sigletons for example to be deallocated? Because if noy you can just drop all current view controllers and present in the root view controller your new controller. If this could help you I will post an answer on how you can do that.

Answer (score 4):

There are no methods available in iOS to restart your application, BUT you could manually reinstantiate initial root `UIViewController` when orientation changes.

---

To reinstantiate root `UIViewController` you could use following *static* functions in your `AppDelegate` class:

```
static func getWindow() -> UIWindow? {
    return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
}

static func resetViewController() {
    let window = getWindow()

    let controller = ...  /// Instantiate your inital `UIViewController`

    window?.rootViewController = controller
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

---

To listen for orientation change use following method in `UIViewController`:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    AppDelegate.resetViewController() /// "Restarts" application
}
```

---

While this is a viable approach, I would highly discourage you from restarting your application when orientation change happens and just handle orientation changes how it supposed to be handled according to Apple.

Comment: small question about your answer because this was what I was thinking, will this deinitialize the sigleton classes? Because with relaunch I understand clear everything in ram.

Comment: No, it will not deinitialize Singletons.